# destructuring and using props in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Says I pass total_counts from parent to a a children component.

In my children component I have a render method

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.pagination.total_counts )
}
```

How do I use total_counts properly without error? My render method of children might render multiple times because pagination came through http call. If I do desctructring like below

```
const { total_counts } = this.props.pagination
render(){
   return (
      <div>{total_counts && <p>{total_counts.toString()}</p>}</div>
   )
}
```

I still have to check total_counts is not undefined

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Try `const { total_counts } = this.props.pagination` ?

Comment: @D-reaper if `this.props.pagination` is undefined, will my app break if I try to render total_counts?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing `total_counts` from `this.props.pagination`, then the destructuring statement should be like this:

```
const { total_counts } = this.props.pagination;
```

This assumes that pagination would never be undefined. Otherwise, I suggest you check it first and fallback to some value if it does not exist;

```js
// default value if this.props.pagination is undefined
let total_counts = 0;

// if this.props.pagination and total_counts property in it exist
// then assign total_counts variable
if (this.props.pagination && this.props.pagination.total_counts) {
  total_counts = this.props.pagination.total_counts;
}
```

Comment: if this.props.pagination is undefined, will my app break if I try to render total_counts?

Comment: It would most likely will be. So, you'd have to check if it's undefined first, if so then fallback to some value.